# Ttk X/Y axis asymmetry?

Tags: python, tkinter, layout, ttk

I'm trying to create a four-way arrow pad using the grid layout engine. I have four arrow images, all rotations of the same image, size 50x26 or 26x50 pixels as appropriate. The right/left ones and the up/down ones are not being equally handled:
[image]

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

leftIcon = PhotoImage(file = "ArrowLeft.png")
upIcon = PhotoImage(file="ArrowUp.png")
rightIcon = PhotoImage(file="ArrowRight.png")
downIcon = PhotoImage(file="ArrowDown.png")
ttk.Button(mainframe, image=leftIcon).grid(column=0, row=1)
ttk.Button(mainframe, image=upIcon).grid(column=1, row=0)
ttk.Button(mainframe, image=rightIcon).grid(column=2, row=1)
ttk.Button(mainframe, image=downIcon).grid(column=1, row=2)
mainloop()
```

What is going on here?  Is there any way to get the desired symmetry apart from editing the .png images to make them square?

Answer (score 2):

The gridder has options that tell it to create rows and columns in the same size. You can set the `uniform` option to any string for all rows and columns, and give them the same weight, and they will all be the same size.

From the canonical documentation about `columnconfigure` (the same applies for `rowconfigure`):

> The **uniform** option, when a non-empty value is supplied, places the column in a uniform group with other columns that have the same value for **uniform**. The space for columns belonging to a uniform group is allocated so that their sizes are always in strict proportion to their **weight** values.

```
mainframe.grid_rowconfigure((0,1,2), uniform="same", weight=1)
mainframe.grid_columnconfigure((0,1,2), uniform="same", weight=1)
```